# rails twitter search different results on heroku WIERD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twitter, tweets

This is the weirdest thing on earth.

I'm using Rails 4 and the twitter gem.

I set a global variable, '$twitter' to access the twitter client.
Local development console:

```
$twitter.search("spinningheelkickpodcast")
```

returns 14 tweets.

Heroku console:

```
$twitter.search("spinningheelkickpodcast")
```

returns 9 tweets.

What the hell? why?

Answer (score 0):

heroku database and local database works independently, They both contains different data.

Comment: There's no database involved. It's just calling the search endpoint and rendering the response

Answer (score 0):

I got same result from both console.

FYI those credentials should be moved out of your initializer and into environment variables e.g. `ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']` etc..

You have a few options with regard to accessing the client throughout the code.

1. Store the Twitter client in a global variable. Global variables are generally considered a bad idea. `$twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(...)`
2. Create a singleton class. This probably won't be thread safe.
3. Use the factory pattern to generate a new client when/where you need it. For example,

In `app/services/twitter_api.rb`:

```
class TwitterAPI
  def client
    @client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.key = ENV['VALUE'] # for each required credential
    end
  end
end

TwitterAPI.new.client.do_something()
```